# Call a class in magento2 code which resides in root

Tags: magento2

May be a very bad question. Not sure.

### Just a brief

I am trying to add simplesamlphp in magento2.

> 1) I added it through composer and its added inside vendor directory.
>   And i can access the classes like this `$auth = new \SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');` And this works..and i can access functions also.

Now the issue is its not written keeping magento2's structure in mind. It will work only if i put the whole code in magento2's root.

### EDIT

**Now if i put the whole code in magento root and try to access like this(dont get me wrong..just try to check with object manager. Wont use it. Chill.)**

```
$object_manager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $dir = $object_manager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');            
        $base = $dir->getRoot();
        $lib_file = $base.'/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php';
        require_once($lib_file);
        $auth = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');
```

It gives me this

> Fatal error: Class
>   'Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple' not
>   found.  // BTW trying to call it from `LoginPost` action.

**How to include classes which are at magento2's root?** (Probably autoload wont work but still)

Answer (score 0):

Try with backslash before

```
$auth = new \SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');
            ^
```

---

> Multiple namespaces may also be declared in the same file. There are
>   simple and bracketed allowed syntaxes.
>
> > **Simple combination syntax**
> >
> > ```
> > <?php
> > namespace MyProject;
> >
> > const CONNECT_OK = 1;
> > class Connection { /* ... */ }
> > function connect() { /* ... */  }
> >
> > namespace AnotherProject;
> >
> > const CONNECT_OK = 1;
> > class Connection { /* ... */ }
> > function connect() { /* ... */  }
> > ```
>
> This syntax is not recommended for combining namespaces into a single
>   file. Instead it is recommended to use the alternate bracketed syntax.
>
> > **Bracketed syntax**
> >
> > ```
> > <?php
> > namespace MyProject {
> >
> > const CONNECT_OK = 1;
> > class Connection { /* ... */ }
> > function connect() { /* ... */  }
> > }
> >
> > namespace AnotherProject {
> >
> > const CONNECT_OK = 1;
> > class Connection { /* ... */ }
> > function connect() { /* ... */  }
> > }
> > ```
>
> It is strongly discouraged as a coding practice to combine multiple
>   namespaces into the same file. The primary use case is to combine
>   multiple PHP scripts into the same file.
>
> To combine global non-namespaced code with namespaced code, only
>   bracketed syntax is supported. Global code should be encased in a
>   namespace statement with no namespace name as in:
>
> > **Unnamespaced code**
> >
> > ```
> > <?php
> > namespace MyProject {
> >
> > const CONNECT_OK = 1;
> > class Connection { /* ... */ }
> > function connect() { /* ... */  }
> > }
> >
> > namespace { // global code
> > session_start();
> > $a = MyProject\connect();
> > echo MyProject\Connection::start();
> > }
> > ```
>
> No PHP code may exist outside of the namespace brackets except for an
>   opening declare statement.
>
> *src: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php*

Comment: Probably you didnt read my post properly. I already tried that. That only works when you have it inside vendor folder.

Comment: Put the code in magento root, it's a bad practices

Comment: Declare multiple namespaces?